# What if someone is incapable of consent?

Tags: ethics

We should refrain from making decisions on behalf of someone who can not consent, correct? Why is that? If we can not decide for them to experience something because they can not consent to the experience, why can we decide for them not to experience said thing? Lack of consent means they can not agree or disagree so who are we to deny them an experience they can not explicitly ask to or not to experience?

Comment: Consent is not a philosophical  notion; it is a legal  notion. When you analyze the notion philosophically it quickly begins to seem arbitrary, even capricious. How is it that someone becomes capable of consent on their eighteenth birthday when they were not capable of consent a minute earlier? The law often has to draw hard lines, even if the lines are sometimes arbitrary.

Comment: You can never *not* make a decision; the choice to do nothing is a decision in itself.  Intuitively I think perhaps you’re asking whether it’s right to change the status quo , and that should as always be done on the basis of whet we believe to be best course of action based on whatever information we have

Comment: @Frog so should the decision to not make a decision be considered as consent or the lack thereof?

Comment: Not doing something is usually less culpable than doing something. So not making someone else do something when they are unable to say no to it is less likely to be a wrongful action.

Comment: @Ahron that’s a slightly different question - if someone is asked for consent but doesn’t respond either way then there’s a strong argument that they have not given consent, and typically a weaker argument that if they disagreed with the consent that was being sought they had an opportunity to decline and didn’t do so.

Comment: *We should ... correct?* No, it's incorrect, and a lame question for this forum. Questions in morality here should define the given system, and not set up childish strawmen.

Answer (score 2):

This question is certainly in the realm of *moral reasoning style*, which was studied by [Lawrence Kohlberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Kohlberg), who discovered [six plus stages of moral development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Kohlberg%27s_stages_of_moral_development). As an individual grows and learns, stages are reached, one at a time, until a person runs out of significant moral dilemmas. Different experiences and proclivities naturally give different results, with most people stopping around stage four. Higher educational attainment correlates with, but does not directly or immediately produce, higher final stage. Later stages can take years to decades each.

Below are the stages, taken from Wikipedia, along with emphasis and notes by me on how a person at each stage may address the moral dilemma in question. In practice, of course, specific cases may go against these predictions, whether from old habit, strong emotion, or outside pressure.

> Level 1 (Pre-Conventional)
>
> - **1. Obedience and punishment orientation**

At this stage, weakness may be seen as inherently immoral. Since lack of ability to give consent is a sign of weakness, wants and well-being of the silent ought to be disregarded. The will of the strong is what matters here.

> - **2. Self-interest orientation**

Someone new to the idea of self-interest is likely to disregard the will and well-being of those unable to consent, choosing instead the path of personal gain.

> Level 2 (Conventional)
>
> - **3. Interpersonal accord and conformity**

When concern for the happiness of peers enters the picture, the best option naturally becomes that which makes the most peers happy. Assuming the one unable to give consent is a peer, this person's happiness will be a big part of the question.

> - **4. Authority and social-order maintaining orientation**

At some point, social roles may become the dominant factor in moral reasoning. Standardised rules and code decide the direction at times of dilemma. Here, laws, rules, and other official norms would likely be consulted to decide how to treat the person unable to give consent.

> Level 3 (Post-Conventional)
>
> - **5. Social contract orientation**

Those with greater concern for edge cases and autonomy, whether individually by one-off agreement, or democratically by vote, would likely reason in terms of social contract. Without having consent at present or by prior agreement, perhaps no action could be rightly taken.

> - **6. Universal ethical principles**

Unlike the *concrete* rules of stage four, and the *idiosyncratic* agreements of stage five, stage six offers [deontological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontology), *abstract* principles. These are to be followed universally, without individual blame for consequences. Rather, the ideology itself, if anything, would be blamed if persistently problematic. Different ideologies and frameworks would give different principles, so the specific possibilities are open-ended.

> [suggested by Kohlberg]
>
> - **7. [Transcendental or Cosmic]**

While stage six may offer abstract *principles*, stage seven may introduce abstract *agents*. For example, individual or universal soul or spirit may become the agent; other species, maybe non-animals, may be included with humans; and concerns of the flesh may be downgraded or even abandoned. Again, any specific action depends on specific beliefs, but a fair chance says compassion would be at play, as stage seven is often the most altruistic.

In conclusion, there is no one-size-fits-all solution to acting in the absence of consent, but the moral reasoning stage is crucial for a given person's style and scope of consideration.

Comment: Like the "five stages of grief," there isn't any hard scientific evidence for such a thing.It's just one guy's opinion of which moral principles are "better" than others. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Kohlberg%27s_stages_of_moral_development#Critiques

Answer (score 1):

Moral reasoning is always *valuating*; it attempts to distinguish better from worse, desirable from undesirable, good from bad, etc; so that a moral agent can choose 'correctly'. That means that moral reasoning is also *directional*. When a route finding app says "Turn left at the intersection", it isn't indifferent whether we turn left or right, because we will only get where we are going if we turn left. Likewise, when moral reasons suggests "do this", it isn't indifferent what we choose. only by 'doing  this' will we achieve what moral reasoning aims at.

People are accepted as moral agents, meaning that we consider them capable of choosing for themselves what they do and do not want. There are various cases where the capacity to exercise moral agency is rescinded, abbreviated, or lost, e.g.:

- Promises and oaths, in which a person voluntarily cedes the ability to choose certain things
- Youth or cognitive impairment, where a person cannot fully understand the nature and consequences of some choices
- Institutionalization or incarceration, in which a person is placed (or places themselves) in custody because they cannot or will not act as moral agents and control certain deleterious behaviors
- Slavery or other forms of repressive control, in which a person is physically constrained from exercising moral agency
- Physical incapacity, where a person is incapable of making certain choices without the assistance of others
- Unconsciousness, where a person is incapable of making any choice, and thus cannot act as a moral agent.

However, even though such people are denied the capacity to act as moral agents in their own right, we still have a moral imperative to treat them as moral agents, and to act as moral agents *in proxy*. We 'ought to' choose for them as they would choose for themselves, or perhaps from the perspective of an abstract, universal moral agent. If we do not do that, we remove their moral agency entirely. We reduce them to *objects* that we manipulate for our own benefit, instead of treating them like *subjects* with their own internal agency.

The concept of consent only applies to direct interaction. We don't generally need consent *not* to interact with someone: e.g., we don't usually have to ask for permission to ignore someone completely. We only need to ask for consent when our intent intrinsically involves interaction with another person (their selves or property). If a person is not capable of giving consent, we cannot morally choose for them to interact with us in the way we desire; we are obliged to choose for them not to interact with us until such a time as they can consent to that interaction on their own.

Answer (score 1):

Your starting thesis is wrong. It is not the case, what you claim, that "We should refrain from making decisions on behalf of someone who can not consent". In the simplest case, doctors treat injured unconscious people.

Why do we do that? Because we believe this is the right course of action and that the person would've consented if they were able to do so.

Comment: That's an exception. I meant generally; outside those rare cases